# Why was Grant Ward's crime not detected when he joined SHIELD Academy?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, agents-of-shield

Towards the end of Agents of SHIELD season 1, we are told that Grant Ward was in Juvenile detention center for setting his house on fire, with his brother inside the house.
Then John Garett breaks him out of prison. So, he was not acquitted of his crime, but a fugitive on the run.
About 5 years later, John Garett says that Grant Ward got accepted into SHIELD Academy (Operations).
Do they not check the person's history? If so, why was Grant Ward's crime not detected?

PS: I've seen all 7 seasons of AoS and all 23 MCU movies. So, do not worry about spoilers. Though I haven't seen other series like Agent Carter, I don't mind spoilers for those (if any).

Comment: I have finished all seasons and rewatching now. So, no problem of spoilers.

Comment: I think they probably will have done the check, but Ward excelled to such a degree that SHIELD admitted him regardless - and chances are Garett vouched for him as well. I imagine that his misdemeanours are on file in a filing cabinet somewhere in SHIELD, but not common knowledge because the organisation is so large. This is all conjecture though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the time of Ward's hiring, S.H.I.E.L.D. had a certain dysfunction in their mission statement.

This particular dysfunction came intensely to light in the movie "Captain America: The Winter Soldier".

Given that, the choice to hire Ward *despite his faults* seems more reasonable, given what we learn of S.H.I.E.L.D. above.

This makes even more sense based on what we learn about Ward in *Agents of S.H.I.E.L.D.* Season 1 Epsiode 20, "Nothing Personal" - the relevant message left by Skye (not yet Daisy) on a window shade.

Comment: Good point - I had forgotten the angle that there would be people within SHIELD at the time who would have fought for Ward's admission - Garett included - for various reasons.

Comment: I have seen winter soldier movie, so it's fine, I know about the "parasite". Though, it would've been better if you had written it explicitly in a spoiler block. So, your point is that the parasite made sure that Ward joins without any hurdles, without knowledge of SHIELD. I find it to believe. It wouldn't take such high risk. It would've tried to bring on Ward legitimately.

Comment: @NagabhushanSN not necessarily without hurdles, but made it easier - given Ward pointers, hints, and fought for his crimes to be overlooked. I should imagine SHIELD knows all about Ward's crimes, but he gave such a glowing interview and various higher-ups said they were so impressed that they recruited him anyway.

Comment: Yeah. That makes sense.